# Entity Framework 6.x: Customize Fluent API in Code First to an Existing Database

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, reverse-engineering, t4

I have installed the [EntityFramework.CodeTemplates](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.CodeTemplates.CSharp/) (as replacement for the previously used Entity Framework Power Tools) and I am struggling to customize the T4 runtime scripts from the files EntityType.cs.t4 and Context.cs.t4 (executed when adding a new "ADO.NET Entity Data Model" to the project and selecting "Code First from Database"). For instance I would like to customize the fluent api code generation and change for instance the property names in the EF entities, to be different from the column names from the mapped tables (which is default).

```
...
modelBuilder.Entity<Department>() 
    .Property(t => t.Name) 
    .HasColumnName("DepartmentName");
...
```

Another customizations that I would need is to be able to change the entity name (to be different from the mapped table name), or to change the names of the different navigation properties between tables:

```
...
modelBuilder.Entity<Department>() 
 .HasMany(e => e.NavigationPropertyName)
...
```

The default code generation of the fluent api code occurs through the MethodChain() helper methods, called at different parts of the Context.cs.t4 runtime script.
I am stuck with the customization of the t4 scripts, as I did not found any samples how to add some additional fluent api code to the default generated fluent api code in MethodChain(). Can anybody post some samples about how this kind of customizations could be done ?